# Why do my HTML buttons refresh the page?/Why can't I get my new HTML DOM Element to insert into my page

Tags: javascript, html, xampp

This should be really simple, but for some reason I just can't seem to get it to work. I'm very new to JS, and I've mostly been using W3 schools to learn (although I've since discovered to MDN ([Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn)), which has proven very useful.

I'm trying to create a new div, append several children to it, and then insert the new div into an HTML form.

Currently I was just trying to run a few test cases make sure that I can get the basic JS working. And I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone know where I'm messing up here?

```js
function AddQueryBox(){
    window.alert("Add QueryBox");
    var NewQBox = document.createElement('div');
    document.createElement('div');
    NewQBox.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Testing"));
    document.getElementById("1").appendChild(NewQBox);
    //document.body.appendChild(NewQBox);
}
```

```html
<div align="right" id="1">
  <select onchange="SwitchDatabaseSet()" name="DBSetList" form="DBSetSelector" id="DBSetSelector">
    <option value="' . $DBSet->DBSetName . '">OPTION</option>
    <option value="' . $DBSet->DBSetName . '">Option</option>
  </select>
</div>

<Form>
  <div>
    <div class="QueryBox" name="QBox">
        <select>
          <option>Option</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text"></input>
        <button>-</button>
    </div>
      <div><button onclick="AddQueryBox()">+</button></div>
  </div>
</Form>
```

DERAIL: This question took a really strange turn... my code works perfectly on stack overflow...but not in XAMPP (dev environment)... Anyone have any ideas about potential causes?

EDIT: Apparently the code is working on my end. But my browser refreshes immediately after the element is added--and removes the element. Because my refresh rate was too fast I didn't see the change. Anybody know why + would make the browser refresh?

Comment: `1` is an invalid identifier for a HTML element. It has to start with a non numerical character.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider not according to the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) for HTML5. In HTML4, a numeric id is illegal, but not anymore.

Comment: Right, I keep forgetting that this was added in HTML5. But that might be the key, if the dev environment uses HTML4 it would explain why it works here.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thanks for that, but It seems to work with an Id of "1". I changed it on my end though. I realized something. I'm not sure what I changed, but It started working on my end. I have this problem though, every time I hit the button, the div is changing and my browser is refreshing too fast. I think that It's actually working, but I couldn't tell due to rapid browser refresh... This is confusing because I don't have any idea why my browser refreshes when I click the + button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your page is reloading because the button is submitting your form.

The submit will, by default, re-load the page to show form errors or the result of the submit action.  The cleanest fix is, as you discovered, to specify a button type.

```
<button type="button">
```

instead of your

```
<button type="submit">
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML page was refreshing immediately after hitting the button. Because my network and load times were fast I didn't notice that anything was happening.

The code actually works just fine in XAMPP, it was just doing the following:

Load Page->User Clicks Button->Insert DIV->Immediate Refresh (Refreshes too quickly to see "Insert DIV" happening)

The reason for this I found is that, if you don't include a "type" attribute on an HTML button, it will refresh the page. Thus the solution was to include 'type="button"' as an attribute to the HTML button tag like so:

```
<div><button type="button" onclick="AddQueryBox()">+</button></div>
```

Comment: You were right that the 'type' was the source of your problem but do you know why? The default 'type' for a button is 'submit' which sends your form to your server using GET (unless your form tag requests post, or you have some other event in place that might use a POST). Other button types are 'reset' which would allow you to reset your form to its initial value when the page was first loaded.