# Clicking on react button asks me to leave site

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react and I have a component which as a 2 input fields and a button, at the moment, clicking on the button will display a message in console log, but when the button is clicked it displays a popup `Leave site?`, `Changes that you made may not be saved.`

[image]

this is my code in this component

```
import React, { useRef, useState, Component } from 'react'
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import { useCollectionData } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';
import { signOut } from 'firebase/auth';

class InfoLgnTest extends Component {
  render() {

      this.state = {
        user: null
      }

    return (
      <div>
         <div className="App">

        <SignInWithEmailPassword />
       </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


function SignInWithEmailPassword() {
   const emailRef = useRef()
   const passwordRef = useRef()

  const signIn = () => {
    console.log("InfoLgnTest singin clicked")
  }

  return (
    <>
          <div className="form">
     <form>
       <div className="input-container">
         <label>Username </label>
         <input 
          name="email"
          type="text" 
          ref={emailRef}
          required 
          placeholder ="something@gmail.com"
          />
       </div>
       <div className="input-container">
         <label>Password </label>
         <input 
          type="text" 
          name="pass" 
          ref={passwordRef}
          required 
          placeholder ="..."
        />
       </div>
       <div className="button-container">
         <input type="submit" onClick={signIn}/>
       </div>
     </form>
   </div>
    </>
  )

}

export default InfoLgnTest
```

Comment: Clicking on the button is submitting the form and triggering page reload.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do my HTML buttons refresh the page?/Why can't I get my new HTML DOM Element to insert into my page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35725859/why-do-my-html-buttons-refresh-the-page-why-cant-i-get-my-new-html-dom-element)

Answer (score -1):

This code has a form, by default form send data as a request on the same page, for resolve this:

- Add `onSubmit` to `form`,
- call `preventDefault` method from `event`
- call the function `signIn`
- Change `<input type="submit" ... />` to `<button type="submit">Send</button>`

```js
function SignInWithEmailPassword() {
   const emailRef = useRef()
   const passwordRef = useRef()

  const signIn = () => {
    console.log("InfoLgnTest singin clicked")
  }

  // new function to handle submit
  const submitForm = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    signIn();
  }

  return (
    <>
          <div className="form">
     {/* Add onSubmit */}
     <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
       <div className="input-container">
         <label>Username </label>
         <input 
          name="email"
          type="text" 
          ref={emailRef}
          required 
          placeholder ="something@gmail.com"
          />
       </div>
       <div className="input-container">
         <label>Password </label>
         <input 
          type="text" 
          name="pass" 
          ref={passwordRef}
          required 
          placeholder ="..."
        />
       </div>
       <div className="button-container">
         {/* Change input to button */}
         <button type="submit">Send</button>
       </div>
     </form>
   </div>
    </>
  )

}
```