# Add string to array on button click in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS and having trouble adding user input to an array. The user input is briefly printing to console but not adding the string to the array on click.

```js
let arrayWords = ['bill', 'sam'];

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', addWord);

function addWord() {
  tmpWord = document.querySelector('input').value;
  console.log(tmpWord);
  arrayWords.push(tmpWord);
}

console.log(arrayWords);
```

```html
<h1>Enter a new word in the box below. Type "stop" to exit.</h1>
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Check the console : Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null

Answer (score 1):

It actually adds it to the array, but you don't see it because you didn't print the array after adding it. Where you put `console.log()` statement works directly, it doesn't work after button click. The mistake you made here is to wait for the operation to print the array to the console after the `addWord()` function runs, since you are waiting like an ordinary code flow.

Since the `console.log()` operation is not triggered by any event in the code you posted, it is executed **as soon as the page is loaded** and the list is printed on the screen in its **initial state** which contains 'bill' and 'sam'. When the input is entered and the button is clicked, you cannot see the new version of the array on the console because you do not print the array with console.log() after the insertion.

Try this;

```js
let arrayWords = ['bill', 'sam'];

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', addWord);

function addWord () {
    tmpWord = document.querySelector('input').value;
    console.log(tmpWord);
    arrayWords.push(tmpWord);
    
    console.log(arrayWords); //print array after the push operation.
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Enter a new word in the box below. Type "stop" to exit.</h1>
    <form>
        <input type="text">
        <button>submit</button>
    </form>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Um, no: the problem - which affects your posted code also - is that the default behaviour of a button, in a form, will submit the form.

Comment: In fact, it is not so, since `console.log()` is run directly in the code given in the question, there is no printing of the array after insertion, so it is displayed as not added to the array.

Comment: @David Thomas thank you! I updated the button tag to include "type=button" to prevent resubmission per: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35725859/why-do-my-html-buttons-refresh-the-page-why-cant-i-get-my-new-html-dom-element